# AlertDialog not displaying Neutral Button Icon

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I'm an inexperienced newbie in android development.
When my method is created, I'm displaying an alert dialog box to select options for the called activity.
However, it doesn't display the neutral button icon, but it calls the relevant actions.
It displays the image on tapping it. Please refer to the code and the image links given below.
The code is this:

```
 initDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                    .setTitle("Select your counter")
                    .setPositiveButtonIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.o))
                    .setPositiveButton("",listener)
                    .setNegativeButtonIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.x))
                    .setNegativeButton("",listener)
                    .setNeutralButtonIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.sq))
                    .setNeutralButton("",listener)
                    .setMessage("Please select your counter.");
            AlertDialog initDialog = initDialogBuilder.create();
            initDialog.show();
```

The sample output is this: [Click here to see sample output with icons attached.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBAqH.jpg)

However, on removing the icon and adding a title, it shows the text. 
The other code with text is this:

```
initDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                    .setTitle("Select your counter")
                    .setPositiveButton("X",listener)
                    .setNegativeButton("O",listener)
                    .setNeutralButton("SQ",listener)
                    .setMessage("Please select your counter.");
            AlertDialog initDialog = initDialogBuilder.create();
            initDialog.show();
```

The output with text instead of the icons is shown here. [Click here to see sample output with text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXrZo.jpg)

What should I do? Any other suggestions to improve my UI? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try This Code ,its working fine for me

> Without netural button text icon not visible so i have added one space in netural button text and set button icon code after show dialog.check below code and screen shot

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    //Uncomment the below code to Set the message and title from the strings.xml file
    builder.setMessage("Custom dialog with neutral button") .setTitle("Just R&D");

    //Setting message manually and performing action on button click
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to close this application ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    finish();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you choose yes action for alertbox",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).setPositiveButtonIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp))
            .setNegativeButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //  Action for 'NO' Button
                    dialog.cancel();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you choose no action for alertbox",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).setNegativeButtonIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)).setNeutralButton(" ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //need to add neutral button text
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })/*.setNeutralButtonIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp))*/;
    //Creating dialog box
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    //Setting the title manually
    alert.setTitle("AlertDialogExample");
    alert.show();

    Button button = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(
            android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);

    // set the bounds to place the drawable a bit right
    drawable.setBounds((int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5),
            0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 1.5),
            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
    button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Thanks @AndroidGeek, this code worked fine. Just had some issues with resizing, that's it. Solved them as well. Thanks once again, sir! <3

Comment: Took me hours to learn that I needed `import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog` not `import android.app.AlertDialog` in order to see the method `setNeutralButtonIcon` method.